# somehow `$scope.selected` is not filled with the right content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

### How to retrieve the selected values of multiple select with AngularJS?

First of all: I am aware of the Angular Multiselect Dropdown module, which I do not want to use! The use case requires a different kind of multiselect, the one that the HTML `<select multiple>` allows and I am trying to realize a way to move items around two of those listboxes.

I already developed some code, which *should* work, but somehow `$scope.selected` is not filled with the right content (or at all). By now, **I think it should be a problem with the setup of the controller** (I am rather new to JavaScript), since going with `ng-model` worked with a simpler example.

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="start.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="Configurator">
            <select multiple ng-model="selected"
                    ng-options="x.name for x in fields">      
            </select>  
        </div>
        {{selected}}
        <button ng-controller="Configurator" ng-click="move() ">Move</button>
        
        <div ng-controller="Configurator">
            <select multiple ng-model="selected2" 
                    ng-options="x.name for x in chosen">      
            </select>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**start.js**

```js
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Configurator', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/fields').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.fields = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    $scope.selected;
    $scope.chosen;
    $scope.selected2;
    $scope.move = function() {
        console.log('function working');
        $scope.chosen = $scope.selected.slice();
        $scope.fields = $scope.fields.filter(x => !$scope.selected.includes(x));
    }
});
```

Why does the above code not work as I expect? `ng-model` should dynamically save the JSONObjects chosen within the multiselect element in the `$scope.selected` element, but it's empty everytime I check via console output and the second multiselect is thereby not filled on button click. What am I doing wrong? Is there a scope issue, because I retrieve the elements via http request? Do I have to initialize `$scope.selected` as an array or move it to a different scope? Honestly, I am out of ideas and things to google, so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: If **multiple** attribute is applied, the value out of select will be an array.

Comment: I know, but what does that mean for my code? I thought about initializing ```$scope.selected``` as an array, but a) it didn't work and b) I read about initialization not being necessary in JavaScript due to dynamic typing.

Comment: Can you create a demo so that I can check what's wrong.

Comment: Your `{{selected}}` is outside of the controller. Either move it into the `<div ng-controller="Configurator">` block or delcare your `ng-controller` on the `<body>` if the controller applies to the whole page.

Comment: @Michael Whoops you are right, thanks! But unfortunately that does not relate to my problem :-)

Comment: @Arcteezy [Here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/9LsPsQdbDOh1gkEBiwj3?p=preview&preview) is a working example of the behavior.

Comment: OK, since you have defined the controller `Configurator` in multiple places you've also created multiple instances of it and seperate scopes, If you put everything under one controller (for example in a div) then this should work as expected. See https://next.plnkr.co/edit/SJoyDk9Er1Msz2kq

Comment: @Michael Holy, I knew it was a rather trivial mistake, but I never payed attention to THAT. Thank you, now that I see it, it's so obvious! I could fix it with this comment (and yes, I noticed the random space in the second ```ng-options``` and fixed that as well). I wish I could accept your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only one controller:

```
<body ng-controller="Configurator">
    <div ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶=̶"̶C̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶u̶r̶a̶t̶o̶r̶"̶ >
        <select multiple ng-model="selected"
                ng-options="x.name for x in fields">      
        </select>  
    </div>
    {{selected}}
    <button  ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶=̶"̶C̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶u̶r̶a̶t̶o̶r̶"̶ ng-click="move() ">Move</button>

    <div ̶n̶g̶-̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶l̶e̶r̶=̶"̶C̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶u̶r̶a̶t̶o̶r̶"̶ >
        <select multiple ng-model="selected2" 
                ng-options="x.name for x in chosen">      
        </select>  
    </div>
</body>
```

Each `ng-controller` directive creates a child scope and because the `ng-model` is binding a scope property, it will be hidden from parent scopes.